# Match any character (including whitespace) until the LAST bunch of whitespaces

Tags: node.js, regex, typescript, regex-group

I've got such text:

```
0000       10   [STUFF]  Text ("TOTAL,SOME RANDOM  TEXT")     (558b6a68)
```

**The first two column is pretty static. The third is optional. The last is optional and if exists, then always covered between parenthesis.**

My issue is with the forth column, which can have spaces or actually any character inside (except newline of course).

My current regex looks like this:

```
^([a-fA-F0-9]{4,})\s+[a-fA-F0-9]+\s+(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s+)?
```

It matches all until the beginning of the fourth column.

**Please note that space might exist anywhere, I can't define exact locations, like "always before parenthesis" or "may be between quotation marks".**

I know for sure that this is the column before the last. So I'd like to capture them like this:

```
 0000       10   [STUFF]  Text("TOTAL,SOME RANDOM  TEXT")      (558b6a68)
 ^  ^                     ^                             ^      ^        ^
CAPTURE                   C    A    P    T    U    R    E     C A P T U R E
```

I'd like to capture the texts marked between ^ ^ characters mentioned in the previous code block.

So, I'd like to grab any character UNTIL the last bunch of whitespace but also I don't want to include them into the final match group.

I hope I described it well :) Is it posssible with regex at all?

Here is some more sample text to test on:

```
0000       10        Text("TOTAL,SOME RANDOM  TEXT")  (1122aabb)
0010        5        D==1122aabb     (1122aabb)
0015       17        Text("AND,SOME,MORE")  (00000001)
002c        5        D==1            (1)
0031        1        !D              (ccdd3344)
0032        5        D==ccdd3344     (ccdd3344)
0037        2        !1              (1)
0039        0 [AAAA] Fff
0039        1 [BBBB] Aaa
003a        6        N(05, eeff5566)  (eeff5566)
0040        1        Qq
0041        2        $ab             ([String]:"Unknown")
0043        f        Call A/SomeFunc-X
0052        1        cd
```

Comment: So what do you actually want to extract/capture? Only the `0000` at start and optionally `(558b6a68)` at the end? Something [like this demo?](https://regex101.com/r/ZqLcE7/2)

Comment: I have updated the post with more example and updated what exactly I'd like to capture.

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ehj0Jo/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd also start similar like your pattern with something like [`^(\w+) +\w+ +(?:\[[^\]]+\] *)?`](https://regex101.com/r/i4gscd/4)

From here (start of 4th column) capture the first `\S` *non white space* followed by `.*?`  [lazily](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) any amount of any character until an optional parenthesized part at the `$` end can be captured. If not, the full line is consumed by group two.

```
^(\w+) +\w+ +(?:\[[^\]]+\] *)?(\S.*?)(?: +(\([^)]+\)))?$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/i4gscd/5)

Feel free to adjust the parenthesis of the third group [to only capture what's inside](https://regex101.com/r/i4gscd/6) if needed.